# Can かまってちゃん be used for males?

Tags: expressions, slang, gender

This word is used to describe someone who bothers or even annoys other people in order to get attention.

The most common translation to English is drama queen, and the Japanese version sounds feminine too, so this has led me to the question.

Can かまってちゃん be used for men aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is used for men as well.

I googled and found many usages.

http://girlschannel.net/topics/146166/ (「わっ！こいつかまってちゃんだ！」と思う男の行動)

http://slism.net/love/kamatteotoko-why.html (かまってちゃん男に好かれるオンナの特徴)

I also found an expression かまってくん for a man.