# Meaning of かまって in the following title

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, て-form, manga

At the end of each tankōbon, the manga [DEAD Tube](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEAD_Tube) has always an extra page with a funny drawing/short story. Every time it has a different title. In the volume in question the title of the extra page is:

> かまって！？水野さん！

In the page, the character called Mizuno is just bored while their friends are away. What is the meaning of かまって in the title? I guess it comes from 構う, but I don't know how to interpret in this context. Is it related to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28757/can-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93-be-used-for-males)? How would you translate the title?

You can see the [original page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vuvo.jpg). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, 「かまって！」 only has one usage at least in Standard Japanese.

It is the "casual request" form of 「構{かま}う」, meaning:

> "Please pay (more) attention to me!"
>
> "Talk to me!" or "Look at me!"
>
> "Don't ignore me!"
>
> "Take (better) care of me!"

It is most often uttered by children, followed by women.

In your manga, a question mark is used, so I would interprete it as: ***"Mizuno looks as if she wanted to say 「かまって！」 to someone/people***".  I know that sounds wordy, but that would be the "feel" of the title to me.

Thus. this is directly related to the other question that you linked to. 「かまってちゃん」 means an "attention-seeker" in colloquial Japanese.